# How to get from datetimepicker only the separated values of the date?

Tags: c#, sql, datetimepicker

How do I get from datetimepicker only the separated values of the date?
For example, for this date (6,5,2017) I want to get--> day=5 , month=6, year=2017.

Answer (score 2):

DateTimePicker value is type [`DateTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=netcore-3.1#properties) which has properties day, month, year.

To access them:

```
dateTimePicker1.Value.Day;
dateTimePicker1.Value.Month;
dateTimePicker1.Value.Year;
```

These properties are read only. To modify it use methods:

Edit (thx to @Richard): AddDays, AddMonths, AddYears methods return new DateTime value that you have to assign back to DateTimePicker.Value

```
dateTimePicker1.Value = dateTimePicker1.Value.AddDays(_days);
dateTimePicker1.Value = dateTimePicker1.Value.AddMonths(_months);
dateTimePicker1.Value = dateTimePicker1.Value.AddYears(_years);
```

Comment: Those modifications statements won't work. `AddDays` (etc) return a new `DateTime` instance,. You need `dateTimePicker1.Value = dateTimePicker1.Value.AddDays(_days)` etc,

Comment: In addition, I need to write sql statement that compare between the current date and the date in the match row, so I wouldn't be allowed to enter the same date to the database.

Comment: so, the `DATEDIFF( DAY, 'date1', 'date2' )` function is used to compare two dates, if the dates are eqauls, it returns 0.